# Rx FRP over angular 2 @Input

Tags: angular

Angular 2 encourages deriving properties from existing ones by using Rx Observables, and having the derived properties `map()` from it.

It also allows passing values to child components (as strings) using `@Input`s. Observables seem to survive serialization cloning by getting passed through an `AsyncPipe` instead, which asynchronously passes through the `Observable`'s values rather than the `Observable` itself.

This leads me to my question: how should I derive properties from `@Input`s if they don't get through as `Observables`? One way that comes to mind is using `NgOnChanges` to intercept new values and reconstructing the Observables from these, but this feels like a dirty hack.

**tl;dr**: how does one Rx `map()` over an angular 2 `@Input` while the `AsyncPipe` exposes only the `Observable`'s values?

Comment: I don't think you can only get strings through `@Input`, have you tried declaring it like this: `@Input observable: Observable;`  and passing an observable to it?

Comment: Hi @Langley, thanks. I was being stupid; the reason my `Observable`s got casted to strings was that I was passing them as `obs="{{obs}}"` rather than `[obs]="obs"`. Lesson learned. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It happens, I'm glad I helped. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can only get strings through @Input, Declare it like this: @Input observable: Observable; and pass an observable to it.

Comment: Attributes only support strings, properties support any type.